# Using a nuget package with a reference to a 2.2 shared framework package in 3.1

Tags: .net-core, nuget

We are currently upgrading some of our applications from dotnet core 2.X to core 3.1 and I have come across an interesting conundrum. We have a shared nuget package which references `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.2.0` and when we are building our new 3.1 version with docker and the 3.1 sdk we are getting errors about being unable to resolve the assembly reference.

I *can* fix this by adding an explicit reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.2.0` to the project but I am interested in the "correct" way approach this problem. It feels like there should be a way to have the package reference either assembly depending on what is installed on the host. Meaning our package can be shared between 2.1 and 3.1.

We *could* create a new package that references the 3.1 shared framework but then we would need some way to distinguish which package to use 2.2 or 3.1 - we would like to avoid pinning our package versions to dotnet core versions because we use our own semver numbering for the packages.

The crux of the question is - what is the best way to manage a package that has a dependency on a previous version of `AspNetCore.App`?

Answer (score 0):

So this seems strange to me but the fix works. It turns out if I reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.0.2` dependency in my nuget package then any consumers of that package work both on 2.x projects and 3.x ones. It's like the core 3.x runtime understands how to deal with a 2.0.2 package but not a 2.1 or a 2.2 one!

I am sure there is a jolly good reason for this but im not clear on what that is!